# Add Columns to Text File in R

Tags: r

I'm using read.delim("x.txt") to read in a txt file.

Using head(df) it outputs:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvBD5.png

I'm trying to add column headers to this file and I'm having trouble figuring out how to do that. It's easier with a csv file!

Comment: What does the text file you're reading in look like? By default `read.delim` uses tabs as a delimiter, so if the columns are delimited by something else, you'll want to specify that.

Answer (score 0):

try `read.delim("x.txt",header=F)` then assign your column headers with:

```
colnames(df) = c("yourname1","yourname2",...)
```

Comment: When I tried assigning the colnames I received the message:

'names' attribute [14] must be the same length as the vector [1]

It's reading the .txt file as one whole column, when theres actually 14 "columns". I'm trying to assign headers to the columns.